# Different PHPUnit versions

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm having an issue with my PHPUnit version (currently version 8).

When I try to run a specific test suite, it's giving me an error, which, based on what I've read online, is a result of the test suite being written for version 7. So, it seems like I'll need to get that version to run the suite. Would you happen to know if I'd necessarily have to uninstall v. 8, or is there a way to overwrite v. 8 with v. 7 (or to have both on my system)?

Answer (score 3):

Using a global installation of PHPUnit is [not recommended](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/installation.html#global-installation). Instead, PHPUnit should be managed as a project-local dependency.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to uninstall it so I can then just use it as a project-local dependency? I cannot remember if I saw anything in the documentation about uninstalling.

Comment: As I do not know how you installed PHPUnit globally I cannot tell you how to uninstall it.

Comment: You might have installed it globally using Composer. Try `composer global remove phpunit/phpunit`.